# POSTFIX does not sender_based_routing with postmap

Tags: routes, smtp, postfix-mta, sender, mail-sender

I try to set up a postfix instance to use sender_based_routing on CentOS6 (but that does not really matter I guess). I just yummed postfix and it works. This is the addition I made for getting sender_based_routing to work:

```
  # CUSTOM
  sender_based_routing = yes
  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

My transport file looks as follows:

```
  domain1.nl smtp:[10.0.8.15]
  domain2.nl smtp:[10.0.8.15]
  * smtp:[10.0.8.14]
```

It always uses the wildcard '*' and all gets routed to 10.0.8.14.

Do I need to specify the complete mail route or just a domain name? I thought the latter was sufficient.

Anyone an idea??

Thanks!

Ronald
Update : When I send 'To' the domain listed in the transport file, then it gets routed through the 10.0.8.15. Have I specified sender_based_routing wrong or do I need an option somewhere else??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Postfix version older than 2.3?

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_based_routing
**sender_based_routing (default: no)**
This parameter should not be used. It was replaced by [sender_dependent_relayhost_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps) in Postfix version 2.3.

Comment: Thanks, figured that out myself yesterday! Postfix rules. If I do not specify a relayhost in the main.cf, will postfix deliver mail directly except for those listed in the relay_map.db file?